# Joomla 3.x - How to add custom buttons to a list view

Tags: view, joomla3.0, joomla3.2

I have a view which displays a list of items.
What I'd like to do is add two buttons ( trash / edit ) to each row.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Need more info.  Are you generating the list programmatically or is this a core Joomla component/module whose display you want to customize?  In addition, are you asking how to render the HTML or are you also wanting help with building out the entire workflow for the two buttons?

Comment: I am writing my own core Joomla component and I want to customize the view. I add the items with a foreach loop to a table, where I'd like to add these two buttons.

Comment: I think I know how to build the workflow, so I would just need the rendering. I found in other standard components JHtml::_(...) for eg status button, but I don't know if or how this could help me.